# What should be the proper commands for pushing a web app via ibmcloud?

Tags: laravel, ibm-cloud

I want 2 deploy a simple laravel app via ibmcloud but I was really having a hard time trying to figure out this crazy workflow. So, the steps that I've done is like this

```
$ ibmcloud login
```

Then what should follow ?

I already did it like this

[image]

Comment: Actually what do you need now, how can we help ?

Comment: I want to host a laravel app via bluemix so that I can give a demo remotely anytime anywhere to my leader.. I've used it 5 years ago but I don't know that it changed drastically including the name of it to ibmcloud

Comment: I already did ibmcloud login,

Comment: IBM Cloud offers (virtual) servers, Kube and OpenShift container, Cloud Foundry and more. What technology are you using? There are subcommands, e.g., `ibmcloud cf` or `ibmcloud ks` for Cloud Foundry and Kubernetes

Comment: I'm using cloudfoundry so I used `cf`

Comment: I already tried 

 
```
bx cf target -o xxx@hotmail.com -s dev --cf-api
FAILED
Use 'bx target' to set or view target org or space.
```

Answer (score 1):

As I see `manifest.yml` file, I am assuming that you are planning to push your app to Cloud Foundry on IBM Cloud. The next steps will be to specify an Org and space interactively

```
ibmcloud target --cf
```

Or, if you know which org and space that the service belongs to, you can use the following command:

```
ibmcloud target -o <value> -s <value>
```

Once specified, deploy your app to IBM Cloud by using the following command

```
ibmcloud cf push
```

For more information on modifying and redeploying your Cloud Foundry app with the command-line interface, refer [this link](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/cloud-foundry?topic=cloud-foundry-cf-deploy-cli&locale=dk)

Comment: λ ibmcloud target --cf
FAILED
Could not get Cloud Foundry instances:
Neither a Cloud Foundry public instance nor a Cloud Foundry enterprise environment was found.

Comment: If you have a billable account, you can add as many orgs as you need. Lite accounts can have only one org, which is already created in your account. 

You can manage Cloud Foundry orgs and spaces by going to Manage > Account and selecting Account resources > Cloud Foundry orgs

Comment: basically, what is cloudfoundry in its essence ?

Comment: Here’s where you can get started - https://www.ibm.com/cloud/cloud-foundry

Comment: awesome, oh ok, can I still host apps today for 30 days..??

Comment: Here's what you get as part of the Lite plan - https://www.ibm.com/cloud/free/

Comment: Yeah I was using Cloudfoundry since it's stated there in the tutorial.. but it's the old version :)  this is the link.. https://www.ibm.com/cloud/blog/getting-started-laravel-bluemix but I'm stuck with the first 3 steps in the Deploying to Bluemix section \there since the links were broken

Comment: Hey, I'm trying to really catch up on this school project that I have to host since it's a must, but I'm having ...a really hard time, sir,I would like to ask for some of your help by really giving me a proper steps to follow can u create something like a gist for it ?

Comment: This is crazy, can someone help me ?